# Error: Invalid account data for instruction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, multisig

I am using the serum multisig program and when I execute the transaction without multisig it works fine, but if I send the create, approve and execute the transaction using multisig it throw the error of `invalid account data for instruction`.

I also send the data need for the program with multisig-safe address in the same way as I send the the data or accounts without multisig. but just get account data with safe address because the tokens are in the multisig not in the sender wallet. But got the error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem. The issue for me was that you have to declare all accounts being accessed not only when you call "executeTransaction" but also those that will be used on the stored transaction that is to be executed.

These just get added as extra account inputs to your "executeTransaction" call.

I was able to parse the solution out of an example test case from the serum multisig wallet.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/multisig/pull/61/files