# Error: unknown signer when trying to move SOL from multisig wallet from nodejs

Tags: multisig, signer

After solving [this problems](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6789/invalid-account-data-on-multisig-token-transfer-from-nodejs) for transferring tokens, I am trying to move the SOL I have in this multisig wallet.
Same signers, but its not working for SOL transfer...
Also non of the explores show this balance beside Nansen.
Looking at the multisig address, its owner is Token program and not System as any other non multisig address. Maybe that is connected to my error, I do think the code is Ok, but I am still getting "Error: unknown signer".

[image]

```
const signer1Account = Keypair.fromSecretKey(key1);
const signer2Account = Keypair.fromSecretKey(key2);
const signer3Account = Keypair.fromSecretKey(key3);


const fromMultisigAddress = new PublicKey('');
const toAddress = new PublicKey(''); 


(async () => {
  let tx = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: fromMultisigAddress,
      toPubkey: toAddress,
      lamports: 1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    })
  );

  const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('confirmed');
  tx.recentBlockhash = await latestBlockHash.blockhash;
  tx.feePayer = signer1Account.publicKey;

 
  console.log(`Transfering SOL from address: ${fromMultisigAddress.toString()} to address:  ${toAddress.toString()} `);
  const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [signer1Account, signer2Account, signer3Account]);
  console.log(`Transferred SOL from address: ${fromMultisigAddress.toString()} to address:  ${toAddress.toString()} `);
  
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issues, there is not way to send out SOL from a token account, so this multisig implementation don't support SOL, and someone did sent it some SOl...

Issue described here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2742

I guess I will have to wait for a fix.

**Update** - fix will be applied only to the token-2022 program so there is no way to send out the SOL from the cli multisig wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Multisig on Solana is handled by Token Program. Thus, you can see from above that owner of your multisig account is Token Program instead of System Program. The other way round is using Wrapped SOL SPL Token instead of native SOL.

Comment: Yes I understand that now. Well, this multisig address is holding SOL coins that I can't move out. Someone used it to receive  SOL and didn't know he will not be able to move it out.