# createInitializeMintInstruction() ----> error: invalid account data for instruction using

Tags: spl-token, mint, error, account-data, initialize

I am trying to use the "createInitializeMintInstruction()" using JS to create a token. The problem is when executing, it throws an error. Concretely this one:

---

Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: invalid account data for instruction

logs: [
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1547 of 399850 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction'
]
}

---

The instruction createInitializeMintInstruction() asks for the following parameteres:

@parameter mint, @parameter decimals, @parameter mintAuthority, @parameter freezeAuthority (optional) and the token program @parameter programId.

Before calling the createInitializeMintInstruction(), I create an account that will be the mint for the token using the following instruction: "SystemProgram.createAccount()". ((using the TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID as well when creating the account))

The account is created succesfully and I pass the parameters correctly to the initializeMint instruction. I don't see why the invalid account data.

(By the way, I'm using TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID from @solana/spl-token)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Invalid account data for instruction](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/error-invalid-account-data-for-instruction)

Comment: kindly share the code how you're creating the account and initializing mint, for better understanding your situation

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm creating spl token with Token Program, which works for me.

```
const { connection } = useConnection();
const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();

const createNewTokenTransaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
    space: MINT_SIZE,
    lamports: lamports,
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }),
  createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mintKeypair.publicKey,
    tokenDecimals,
    publicKey,
    publicKey,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
);
await sendTransaction(createNewTokenTransaction, connection, { signers: [mintKeypair] });
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked.

I checked several times but I didn't notice that the initializeMintInstruction was asking for a publickey, and I was actually passing a full keypair by mistake.

Thanks for the code though!!